# Python: How can I test a recursive method?

Tags: python-2.7, recursion, scandir

Long time listener, first time caller.

I've written a **python 2.7** method that performs a recursive scan (using `scandir`) on a given directory that has has some `find`-like functionality (ie, you can specify a `mindepth` and `maxdepth`):

```
def scan_tree(self, search_path, max_levels=-1, min_levels=-1, _level=0):
    """Recursively yield DirEntry objects for given directory."""
    max_out = max_levels > -1 and _level == max_levels
    min_out = min_levels > -1 and _level <= min_levels

    for entry in scandir(search_path):
        if entry.is_dir(follow_symlinks=False) and not max_out:
            for child in self._scan_tree(entry.path, max_levels,
                                         min_levels, _level + 1):
                if not child.is_dir(follow_symlinks=False):
                    yield child

        elif not min_out:
            yield entry
```

The thing is, I can't for the life of me figure out the best/proper way to write a unit test that will allow me both to `mock` the recursive `scandir` calls properly **and** test the behaviour of my minimum and maximum scanning parameters.

Normally I'd use `scandir.walk` to do the scanning (I've already written a properly testable version of that), but I really need the information on the `DirEntry` instances that `scandir` spits out.

Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I was able to get back to a testable state by setting up a `walk`-like method using `scandir` as a basis (ie, returning a tuple of `(root, dir_entries, file_entries)`) and using a similar `mock` strategy to the one that initially worked for `walk`, but I'd love to figure out how to handle the initial recursive issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can present an alternative solution:

**Create your directory structure**

Turning things around: Ask yourself 'what is it I want?'. I presume it's to have a fixed directory structure to test against. We can create such a structure using the `os` package functions such as [makedirs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html) instead, and simply call the real `scandir`, but fix the `search_path` to be a fixed 'testdir': a subdirectory of the current working directory.

E.g. do something like:

```
basedir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
os.makedirs(os.path.join(basedir, '/testdirectory/first/second'))
os.makedirs(os.path.join(basedir, '/testdirectory/another/'))
"""You can create some additional empty files and directories if you want"""
"""(...)"""
"""Do the rest of your work here"""
```

Then, as a cleanup operation in your error handler and at the end of your test, don't forget to call this to remove the temporary files:

```
shutil.rmtree(os.path.join(basedir, '/testdirectory/'))
```

The benefit of working with real directories is that we can have python's abstractions of OS differences and peculiarities continue to work, instead of having to re-create them to make the test code properly mimic what the real thing will encounter.

Code examples in this answer do not have exception handling in them. You'll have to add this yourself.